# How can I dynamically manipulate props in TaskList?

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react. I stuck in removing card from screen with onClick button. From this point I can get this.props.data and if I console.log(this.props.data) it return me

```
(2) [Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
```

So I want to know how can I remove object from `this.props.data`. When I use `splice` method with index (which is actually an id of object) in this way `this.props.data.splice(index, 1)` it doesn`t work correctly, but item are disappear from screen. This func is deleting everything in array in order, from beginning to the end. Please, explain me how can I get best solution for this achievement.

here is code:

```
import React from "react";
import TaskList from './TaskList';
import update from 'immutability-helper';
import './../stylesheets/main.scss';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        localStorage.getItem("tasks") ? (this.state.tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.tasks)) : (this.state.tasks = []);
    }

    addTask(id) {
        const newTasks = this.state.tasks;
        let task = {type: 'do_it', id: '0', description: '', priority: '', time: new Date().toLocaleString()};
        let desc = document.getElementById("description").value;
        let cardPriority = document.getElementById("priority-selector").value;

        task.id = newTasks.length + 1;
        task.description = desc;
        task.priority = cardPriority;
        newTasks.push(task);
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(newTasks));
        this.setState({
            tasks: newTasks
        })
    }

    handleDrop(id, toType) {
        const tasks = this.state.tasks;
        const taskIndex = tasks.findIndex((task) => {
            return task.id == id;
        });
        const updatedTask = update(tasks[taskIndex], {type: {$set: toType}});
        const newTasks = update(tasks, {
            $splice: [[taskIndex, 1, updatedTask]]
        });
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(newTasks));
        this.setState({tasks: newTasks});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-home">
                <div className="input">
                    <div className="inner">
                        <h1>Kanban Board</h1>
                        <input name="description" type="text" id="description"/>
                        <select name="priority" id="priority-selector">
                            <option value="">Priority:</option>
                            <option value="1">1: High</option>
                            <option value="2">2: Medium</option>
                            <option value="3">3: Low</option>
                        </select> <br/>
                        <button type="submit" className="submit" onClick={this.addTask.bind(this)}>Add task</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="column">
                        <h2>Do it</h2>
                        <TaskList
                            data={this.state.tasks}
                            type={'do_it'}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="column">
                        <h2>In Progress</h2>
                        <TaskList
                            data={this.state.tasks}
                            type={'in_progress'}
                            allowedTypes={['do_it']}
                            handleDrop={this.handleDrop.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="column">
                        <h2>Done</h2>
                        <TaskList
                            data={this.state.tasks}
                            type={'done'}
                            allowedTypes={['in_progress']}
                            handleDrop={this.handleDrop.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="column">
                        <h2>Aborted</h2>
                        <TaskList
                            data={this.state.tasks}
                            type={'aborted'}
                            allowedTypes={['do_it', 'in_progress']}
                            handleDrop={this.handleDrop.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and here is TaskList class:

```
import React from "react";
import { Draggable, Droppable } from 'react-drag-and-drop'
import update from 'immutability-helper';

export default class TaskList extends React.Component {

    static getElementId(e) {
        let id = null;
        for (let key in e) {
            if (e[key] !== '') {
                id = e[key];
            }
        }
        return id;
    }

    static sortByPriority(a, b) {
        return b.priority - a.priority;
    }

    onDrop(e) {
        if (!e) return;
        const id = TaskList.getElementId(e);
        this.props.handleDrop(id, this.props.type)
    }

    orderTasks() {
        const tasks = this.props.data.filter((el) => {
            return el.type === this.props.type;
        });
        // tasks.sort(TaskList.sortByPriority);

        tasks.sort(function (a, b) {
            return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
        });

        return tasks;
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    editTask(e) {

        //var desc = e.target.value;
        //
        //this.setState({
        //    tasks: {description: desc}
        //})

    }

    deleteTask(index) {

        var state = this.props.data;

        console.log(index);

        state.splice(index, 1);

        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(state));

        this.setState({
            tasks: state
        })
    }

    render() {
        const tasks = this.orderTasks();

        return (
            <Droppable
                className="list" types={this.props.allowedTypes}
                onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
            >
                <ul>
                    {tasks.map((task) => {

                        return (
                            <Draggable
                                type={this.props.type}
                                key={task.id}
                                data={task.id}
                            >
                                <li>
                                    <div className="card">

                                        <b>Task description:</b><br/>

                                        {task.type === 'do_it' ?

                                            <form>
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    defaultValue={task.description}
                                                    onChange={this.editTask.bind(this)}
                                                />
                                                <input
                                                    type="button"
                                                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
                                                    value="Edit"
                                                />
                                            </form>

                                            : <p>{task.description}</p>}

                                        <p><b>Time: </b>{task.time}</p>

                                        <div className="priority"><b>Priority:</b> {task.priority}</div>

                                        {task.type === 'aborted' ? <button className="close"
                                                                           onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this, task.id)}>&times;</button> : null}
                                        {task.type === 'done' ? <button className="close"
                                                                        onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this, task.id)}>&times;</button> : null}
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </Draggable>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </Droppable>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using arrays, you can do something like this to remove a task card from DOM:

```
deleteTask: function(e) {
  var index = this.props.items.indexOf(e.target.value);
  this.props.items.splice(index, 1);
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I had no idea that forceUpdate() existed! Thank you for teaching me something new. But it looks like the React team discourages the use of forceUpdate(). It is better to use the state and props in this case (without manually mutating them). 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: Yes indeed forceUpdate() is deprecated and will not be there in the future releases of react. And yes, one should never mutate state and props directly. I quoted this example as you said "I am very new to react". Glad I could teach you something!

Comment: @m-ketan Thank you, but somehow this solution isn't work for my app.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you add a task by adding it to your state, you will have to update your state to a new set of tasks that do not include the task that you are trying to delete, and then React will remove the deleted task from the DOM. In your deleteTask function:

```
this.setState( state => ({ tasks : state.tasks.filter(x => x.id !== id ) }))
```

Just a note: in general you want to avoid directly mutating this.state as you are doing in addTasks when you push a new item. Instead consider creating a new array using the [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function of an array:

```
this.setState( state => ({ tasks: state.tasks.concat(task) }) )
```

Or using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) from ES6:

```
this.setState( state => ({ tasks: [...state.tasks, task)] }))
```

Note that `this.setState` can take an object as a parameter, or a function. When it takes a function, the function has the current state as a parameter and it is garunteed to be the updated state of the component. For performance reasons, React will sometimes not update the state right away, and if you just call `this.setState` with an object, it isn't guaranteed that the entire state will be up to date.

Comment: Just an additional note: The important thing in React is that you never "delete something from render". You update your app's state and this change triggers a new render, which updates the view to reflect the state.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my goal by simple `for` loop like this:

```
deleteTask(id) {

        const state = this.props.data;

        for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {

            if (state[i].id === id) {

                let current = state[i];

                state.splice(state.indexOf(current), 1);
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(state));

        this.setState({
            tasks: state
        })
    }
```